# Why tkinter ask open file has a low resolution?

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog

In this picture you can see that the left dialog has a lower resolution then then right one.

[image]

Why folders are different?

I'm working with Python 3 and here's my code

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/",
    title = "Select a File",
    filetypes = (("Text files", "*.txt*"), ("all files", "*.*"))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. You just have to import the `pyautogui` module into program.

```
import pyautogui
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is using the call() function to change the resolution scaling.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")
root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2.0)

askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select a File",filetypes = (("Text files","*.txt*"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from pyscreeze import pixel
```

Or on Windows:

```py
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import ctypes
    try:
       ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```